# Shockwave-flash in Chrome bugs the page's background

Tags: html, flash, google-chrome

I noticed that my website's behavior has changed lately in Chrome. It comes from the piece of code shown here. With that code the page works fine and all seems to be ok (the flash banner is ok too). BUT as soon as I scroll the page, I notice that the background is white (all that was not shown when the page originally loaded). It's like if the background is not loaded out of the original shown page sight. If I remove the piece of code emphasized, the banner doesn't load the animation, but the background loads properly.

What prevents me page's backgroung from loading properly? Note that this is the only flash code/object on my whole website.

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="994" height="250"
                            id="art-flash-object">
                            <param name="movie" value="images/container.swf" />
                            <param name="quality" value="high" />
                            <param name="scale" value="default" />
                            <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                            <param name="flashvars" value="color1=0xFFFFFF&amp;alpha1=.50&amp;framerate1=24&amp;loop=true&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;clip=../../Content/images/flash.swf&amp;radius=5&amp;clipx=-3&amp;clipy=0&amp;initalclipw=1000&amp;initalcliph=250&amp;clipw=1000&amp;cliph=250&amp;width=994&amp;height=250&amp;textblock_width=0&amp;textblock_align=no&amp;hasTopCorners=true&amp;hasBottomCorners=true" />
                            <param name="swfliveconnect" value="true" />
```

#### Shockwave code here causes the bug

```
                            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="../../Content/Images/container.swf"
                                width="994" height="250">
                                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                                <param name="scale" value="default" />
                                <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                                <param name="flashvars" value="color1=0xFFFFFF&amp;alpha1=.50&amp;framerate1=24&amp;loop=true&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;clip=../../Content/images/flash.swf&amp;radius=5&amp;clipx=-3&amp;clipy=0&amp;initalclipw=1000&amp;initalcliph=250&amp;clipw=1000&amp;cliph=250&amp;width=994&amp;height=250&amp;textblock_width=0&amp;textblock_align=no&amp;hasTopCorners=true&amp;hasBottomCorners=true" />
                                <param name="swfliveconnect" value="true" />
                                <div class="art-flash-alt">
                                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif"
                                            alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </object>
```

#### End of buggy code

```
</object>
```

Comment: Possibly can be realted to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768474/chrome-flash-player-creates-transparent-rectangles-in-the-flash-window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's the cause of the problem, but in the first piece of code there's no `</object>` closing tag present.

Also, I have experienced some flash loading issues with relative paths (like you did with `value="images/container.swf" />` and `data="../../Content/Images/container.swf"`). Never knew what exactly was the issue there, but try loading the flash file from the same folder as where your .html file is located.

I myself sometimes use the html code generated by Flash (under Publish..) because sometimes that seems to be the only working code in order to show the Flash correctly.

P.s. I don't understand exactly what's the deal with the two `<object>` tags and their contents, did you use both at the same time, separately, or...?